# Kafka Stream Startup Issue - org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LockException

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Streams Application version - 0.11 which takes data from few topics and joins the data and puts it in another topic.

Kafka Configuration:

```
5 kafka brokers - version 0.11
Kafka Topics - 15 partitions and 3 replication factor.
```

Few millions of records are consumed/produced every hour. Whenever I take any kafka broker down, it throws below Exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LockException: task [4_10] Failed to lock the state directory for task 4_10
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.<init>(ProcessorStateManager.java:99)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.<init>(AbstractTask.java:80)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StandbyTask.<init>(StandbyTask.java:62)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.createStandbyTask(StreamThread.java:1325)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.access$2400(StreamThread.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$StandbyTaskCreator.createTask(StreamThread.java:313)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$AbstractTaskCreator.retryWithBackoff(StreamThread.java:254)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addStandbyTasks(StreamThread.java:1366)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.access$1200(StreamThread.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$RebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned(StreamThread.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:363)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:310)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1078)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1043)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:582)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:553)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:527)
```

I have read at few jira issues that cleaningUp the streams might help to fix the issue. But cleaningUp the streams everytime we start the Kafka Stream Application is a right solution or a patch? Also, stream cleanUp will delay the application startup right?

**Note: Do I need to call streams.cleanUp() before calling streams.start(), each time I start the Kafka Streams application**

Answer (score 1):

Seeing a `org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.LockException: task [4_10] Failed to lock the state directory for task 4_10` is actually expected and should resolve itself. The thread will back off in order to wait until another thread releases the lock and retries later. Thus, you might even see this WARN message is the logs multiple time in case the retry happens before the second thread did release the lock.

However, eventually the lock should be release by the second thread and the first thread will be able to get the lock. Afterwards, Streams should just move forward. Note, it's a WARN message and not an error.

Comment: But it takes too long to resolve this warning. Is there a config to reduce the number of retries for this.

Comment: And ideally should I call cleanup() Everytime I start my stream instance?

Comment: No. You should not! It would introduce a lot of unnecessary overhead! Compare the "Tip" box in the docs: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#step-2-reset-the-local-environments-of-your-application-instances

Comment: I am continuously getting the above exceptions and it is in the above state for last 12 hours. 

2017-09-14 06:32:04 - [WARN] [view-live-cb2c9b8b-4979-45bc-bf5d-51212242b67e-StreamThread-1] [org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.retryWithBackoff:283] : stream-thread [view-live-cb2c9b8b-4979-45bc-bf5d-51212242b67e-StreamThread-1] Still retrying to create tasks: [2_3]

Comment: Is there any solution to resolve this. It looks like the second thread is not releasing the lock and thus first thread is not able to get the lock of that state dir. Please help.

Comment: Should I increase retry.backoff.ms ? I am running 3 instances of same Kafka Stream Application on same machine do I need to change the state.dir? Can state.dir be the reason for lock?

Comment: `retry.backoff.ms` is a different configuration and has no effect here. If you end up in a bad state, maybe using `KafkaStreams#cleanup()` (just a single time) might resolve the issues (as you say it keeps logging this warning for multiple hours, the application is in a bad state). Maybe you can upgrade to 0.11.0.1 (was released today) -- it contains a bug fix that might be related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5167

Comment: I don't think 0.11.0.1 is released yet. Not able to find latest maven dependency for it. But Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am running 3 instances of same Kafka Stream Application on same machine do I need to change the state.dir? Can state.dir be the reason for lock?

Comment: Kafka (and the Kafka Streams library/artifact) version 0.11.0.1 is released and available from Maven Central: https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.kafka%7Ckafka-streams%7C0.11.0.1%7Cjar

Comment: [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.sendJoinGroupRequest:432] : (Re-)joining group view-live
[INFO] [view-live-StreamThread-1] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.coordinatorDead:642] : Marking the coordinator 172.11.31.1:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null) dead for group view-live
[INFO] [view-live-4ec94daa6227-StreamThread-1] [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.onSuccess:597] : Discovered coordinator 172.11.31.1:9092 (id: 2147483644 rack: null) for group view-live.

Comment: Upgrading to 0.11.0.1, my stream join stopped working. Any idea? I have above configurations mentioned in question except Kafka Stream Application are running separately on 3 boxes and kafka brokers on 5 brokers separately.

Comment: Changing state.dir is the same as using `clenup()` once -- in both cases you start with an empty directory and thus, no locks should be held. If the lock issues does not go away, please create a new JIRA and attach your logs in DEBUG mode. Btw there is one more workaround you can try: cf https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Igetalockingexceptionsimilarto"Causedby:java.io.IOException:Failedtolockthestatedirectory:/tmp/kafka-streams/<app-id>/0_0".HowcanIresolvethis?

Comment: About the join. No idea. I don't think 0.11.0.1 does anything different here: cf. https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/0.11.0.1/RELEASE_NOTES.html